# Передача команды с Android устройства через USB на PC

Tags: android, usb

Как можно реализовать передачу команд с Android устройства через USB на PC. Пример: на телефоне есть приложение с кнопкой, по нажатию на которую передаётся текст в программу на компьютер. Интересен сам процесс передачи данных через USB (где об этом можно почитать книги, статьи не важно что).

Comment: Только если вас устраивает вариант с пересборкой ядра Linux для вашего Android-устройства, с которого вы хотите передавать команды.

Comment: Это будет сильно зависить от ОС на компе, добавьте подробностей, что хотите, какая ось и т.д.

Comment: Windows, скажем так, нужно передать текст из переменной в программу на компьютере.